# On click not working for dynamically added link id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, dom-events

I have a link and on page load I am dynamically adding an "id" , the link say logoff.

On clicking logoff link I need to perform an ajax. I was able to add id but on click is not working.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#main-navigation li').each(function(index) {
        var text =  jQuery.trim($(this).text());
        if (text == "Log Off") {
            $(this).children().attr('id',"log_out_link");
        }
    });
});
$(document.body).on('click', '#log_out_link', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("edsddd");
    return false;
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

ANSWER:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#main-navigation li').each(function(index) {
        var text =  jQuery.trim($(this).text());
        if (text == "Log Off") {
            $(this).children().attr('id',"log_out_link");
            // onclick staff here
            $('#log_out_link').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("edsddd");
                return false;
            });
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: What's the HTML look like?

Comment: `$(this).text()` will always get the text of li and text of its children , 
the statement  `if (text == "Log Off") { ... }` will not work in your case .so there no element with #log_out_link id

Comment: Actually this code does add id to log off menu.. my issue is after adding it dynamically on page load the on click event is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. jQuery find DOM where it will be added.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#main-navigation li').each(function(index) {
        var text =  jQuery.trim($(this).text());
        if (text == "Log Off") {
            $(this).children().attr('id',"log_out_link");
            // onclick staff here
            $('#log_out_link').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("edsddd");
                return false;
            });
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you are adding the `id` after the `document` is ready and then adding a listener to that `id` from the preloaded `document`.

try using

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
              $('ul#main-navigation li').each(function(index) {
                 var text =  jQuery.trim($(this).text());
                 if (text == "Log Off") {
                     $(this).children().attr('id',"log_out_link");
                 }
              });
            });
            $('#log_out_link').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("edsddd");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a text-content of an `li` which cntains other nodes (result is text of `li` + its child nodes so will never be equals to  "Log Off" ) ,

you can get the text of the node by cloning it removing its children and get its text only , si your `if` statement here will work correctly

```
$(this).clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

Also it's incorrect to set same ids for multiple nodes ( children of `li` node ) so use class instead :

See below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul#main-navigation li').each(function(index) {
    var text =jQuery.trim($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
    console.log(text);
    if (text == "Log Off") {
      $(this).children().attr('class', "log_out_link");
    }
  });
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.log_out_link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("edsddd");
  return false;
});
```

```css
p.log_out_link {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main-navigation">
  <li>Log On</li>
  <li>Log In<p><a>text</a></p><p><a>text</a></p></li>
  <li>Log Off
    <p><a>text</a></p><p><a>text</a></p></li>
  <li>Log Out<p><a>text</a></p><p><a>text</a></p></li>
</ul>
```